HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute is not working in .NET 4.8
In my .cshtml page, we are calling an .aspx page through virtual path (eg. /includes/header.aspx) and trying to convert its output into a string and embed on the page.
But it's throwing this error:

HttpException: The file '/includes/header.aspx' does not exist

I tried executing the output of the .aspx page, converting its output into string and embedding into cshtml page using HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute as shown below.
using(new Tracer(virtualPath, httpContext.Request, httpContext.Request.Url))
{
    using(StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(virtualPath, stringWriter);
        var stringBuilder = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder();
        razorOutput = stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}


I suspect this is not possible. In MVC there is no HTML output until after the CSHTML file has been processed by the Razor rendering engine, and only then the entire HTML output gets written to the Response stream.

But it's working in our previous versions. It's not working in .net 4.8 version.
